# Updating Word Documents

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I am using WORD 2010. I write many procedures and some steps are redundant between 2 documents. Is there a way to link the documents so if I update a redundant step from one document it will automatically update the redundant step in the other document?

Answer (score 0):

1. In one of the documents ('document A'), select the text of the first redundant step. I generally prefer to select just the text content of the paragraph, omitting the ¶ mark at the end. (If necessary, make paragraph marks visible by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>.) Then, on the **Insert** tab, in the **Links** group, click **Bookmark** to insert a bookmark. It's a good idea to make a note of your bookmark names (for example, copy and paste them into a Notepad file), because you'll have to enter them manually later.

   If the steps in several consecutive paragraphs will be redundant, select all of them at once (I omit the ¶ mark at the end of the last step in the group). Insert a bookmark for that group of steps.
2. Repeat step 1 until all the redundant steps and/or groups of steps are bookmarked.
3. In the other document ('document B'), insert a blank paragraph where you want to insert a redundant step or group of steps from document A.
4. Use one of these methods to insert the text of the step or group of steps as an `INCLUDETEXT` field:

   - On the **Insert** tab, in the **Text** group, click **Object** > **Text from File**. Select document A. Click **Range**, and then enter the name of the bookmark that corresponds to the step or group of steps. Finally, click the arrow on the right side of **Insert** button, and then click **Insert as Link**. This last part is important. If you just click the **Insert** button, the step or steps will be inserted as static (non-updatable) text.
   - On the **Insert** tab, in the **Text** group, click **Explore Quick Parts** > **Field**. In the **Field names** list, select **Include text**, and then click **Field Codes**. After `INCLUDETEXT`, type the file name for document A, and then type the name of the bookmark for the step or group of steps. Enclose the file name in quotation marks if it contains spaces, and enter the full path of the file if documents A and B aren't in the same directory.
   - Manually add the field code by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. Between the braces (`{}`), type `INCLUDETEXT [file name or path, as above] [bookmark name]`.

     For example, my document A is named CreatingAReport.docx and is in the same directory as document B. I want to insert a group of steps that explain how to set up the printer. In document A, I have added a bookmark, named SettingUpThePrinter, for those steps. In this case, my field code would look like this:

     > `{ INCLUDETEXT CreatingAReport.docx SettingUpThePrinter }`

   If document A contains fields, such as date fields, that shouldn't be updated when the content is inserted into document B, unless you explicitly update them in document A, you can add a `!\` switch to the field code that is inserted by any of three methods.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 for every redundant step or group of steps.

Once you've done this, you can make changes to the bookmarked text in document A and then update document B so that it shows those changes. Or, you can make changes to the inserted text in document B and save those changes back to document A:

- Make changes to the bookmarked text in document A, and then save the file. In document B, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the whole document, and then press <kbd>F9</kbd> to update all fields in it.
- Make  changes to the inserted text in document B, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to update the corresponding bookmarked text in document A.

**Note:** If the steps in your documents are autonumbered, and you insert a group of steps via a single bookmark, you might find that the numbering for those steps restarts at 1. The most reliable way to fix this, I've found, is to wait until all the steps have been added to a given procedure, and then completely remove and reapply numbering to the whole procedure (or, better yet, wait until all the steps are added before you apply numbering in the first place). If you try to right-click the number for the first step in the group, and then click **Continue Numbering**, the numbering for all or some of the groups of steps will likely be reset to 1 or some other strange value when you update field codes later.